# How to run python script in Android studio using chaquopy?

Tags: python, android, chaquopy

I am trying to use python script in the Android studio using chaquopy. But I have 2 problems.

1. I am not able to import `python random`.
2. How to retrieve a list.

Here is the Python Script.

```
import random
def getPlayers(wk, batsman, bowler, allRounder):
    chosen = batsman[:3] + bowler[:3] + allRounder[:1] + wk[:1]
    remainder = batsman[3:] + bowler[3:] + allRounder[1:] + wk[1:]
    random.shuffle(remainder)
    chosen.extend(remainder[:3])

    players = {'Batsman': [x for x in chosen if x in batsman],
               'Bowler': [x for x in chosen if x in bowler],
               'AllRounder': [x for x in chosen if x in allRounder],
               'Wk': [x for x in chosen if x in wk]}

    for key in players:
        for name in players[key]:
            return f'{key}: {name}'
```

It is showing no module named random found.

**And The activity file**

```
 private String getTeam() {
    Python python = Python.getInstance();
    PyObject file = python.getModule("getTeam");
    return file.callAttr("getPlayers", wk, batsman, bowler, ar);
}
```

I am calling `getTeam` method in `onCreate`. So, How can I get the list of keys and values from `python` script?

**EDIT**

I have used this code to access the data but It is showing `com.chaquo.python.PyException: TypeError: jarray does not support slice syntax`.

Here is the Code

```
  String[] team = getTeam();
    for (String s : team) {
        Log.d("Player", s);
    }

}

private String[] getTeam() {
    Python python = Python.getInstance();
    PyObject file = python.getModule("getTeam");
    return file.callAttr("getPlayers", wk.toArray(), batsman.toArray(), bowler.toArray(), ar.toArray()).toJava(String[].class);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is showing no module named random found.

I assume you're talking about an error shown in the Android Studio editor, rather than one which happened at runtime. As [the documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-studio-plugin) says, errors in the editor are harmless: just go ahead and run your app, and if there really is an error, the details will be displayed in the [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html).

> How can I get the list of keys and values from python script?

You can write the Python code like this:

```
return [f'{key}: {name}' for key in players for name in players[key]]
```

And the Java code like this:

```
file.callAttr("getPlayers", wk, batsman, bowler, ar).toJava(String[].class)
```

That will give you a Java `String[]` array, which you can then process however you want.

---

**EDIT** for `jarray does not support slice syntax`:

**This issue is fixed in Chaquopy 9.0.0.** With older versions, you can work around it by converting the array to a Python `list`.

To convert in Python:

```
def getPlayers(wk, batsman, bowler, allRounder):
    wk = list(wk)
    batsman = list(batsman)
    # etc.
```

Or to convert in Java:

```
PyObject list = python.getBuiltins().get("list");
return file.callAttr("getPlayers", 
                     list.call(wk.toArray()), 
                     list.call(batsman.toArray()), 
                     // etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there is a problem it shows an error that is ** com.chaquo.python.PyException: TypeError: 'ArrayList' object is not subscriptable**. Any Suggestions?

Comment: If `wk, batsman, bowler, ar` are all ArrayLists, then you should call [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray--) to convert them before passing them to Python.

Comment: The Code is working but I am unable to use it. I have made an Edit Section in my question please check.